# SQL Server Fact table indexing

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a data warehousing environment and have a question about indexing.  I have a header fact table which then joins to a detail level fact table.  The detail fact table then joins to many dimensions.

So we have:

```
FactHeader
FactDetail

Dim1
Dim2
Dim3
Dim4
```

In my queries I need to join `FactDetail` to all of the dimension tables to get descriptions for reporting needs.

I have a nonclustered index on `FactDetail.FactHeaderKey`. My question is: should I include all of the foreign keys in this non clustered index or should I create separate non clustered indexes on the foreign keys?  If I create separate indexes it is doing a clustered index scan, which is just on the identity column.

If I create the one non clustered index then it does an index seek and of course returns all of the foreign keys along with it.  To me it seems like I should just do the one nonclustered index with the include, but for some reason that doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So when you design Indexes, it be based on OLTP or OLAP.  Since yours is a data warehouse your indexes will be based on OLAP.  So the rule with creating individual indexes on Foreign Keys is for OLTP database designs.  Since OLAP is mainly for data retrieval you will design your indexes mainly on the queries.  Index Architecture is very important, because its expensive just to include all columns in the B-Tree.  But if your query has a join on all the related tables then yes, have one non-clustered index with those Foreign Keys.